# I need the behavior of media queries to change layout inside individual divs

Tags: css, media-queries

The grid layout of my site changes relative to the width of the browser viewport by using CSS3 Media Queries.

But now I'm looking for a way to change layouts of specific blocks in my grid. So they behave differently relative to the width of their parent element.

For example, if the parent element is +500px wide, I can show titles with thumbnails, if the parent element is less than 500px wide, only titles are shown, in a bigger font-size.

If even possible, what's the best approach for this? Preferably without the use of JavaScript.

This approach should allow me to write one block of HTML that could be reused on any site, anywhere on a page, with or without a responsive layout.

Comment: Further investigation concludes this is not possible with CSS3 alone. I'll need to use JavaScript in order to calculate each individual block and add "width-n" classes to change layout. Kinda sad that W3 could't foresee this.

Answer (score -1):

if you're using media queries already, just add what you want to them;
regular css:

.parent .child .thumbnails,.parent .child .titles{display:block}  -500px

-500 px css:
@media only screen and (max-width :500px) { .parent .child .thumbnails{display:none;}

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. Media Queries are relative to the width browser viewport. I need the layout of a block to change, not based on the viewport width, but based on the width of it's parent element...

Comment: i did misunderstand dude, sorry